# old project React-Redux : nativeEvent.path undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

I'm following along a step by step to create a character sheet with React-Redux.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPlejG83B1Y&list=PLJ-47dnNMd_jke6l27GmEiDk5XJGcr_HE&index=5

I have vague notions of React (begun a tutorial some year ago), but I understand lots of stuff is deprecated in this code.

I stumble on this error, but I don't think this is because nativeEvent is deprecated.

On firefox:

> ```
> ERROR
> action.payload.nativeEvent.path is undefined
> ```

On opera gX:

> ```
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')
> ```

I was thinking the `payload` in `traitsActions.js` is maybe ill-defined or the following line is deprecated, but I can't find the real way to implement it (tried the Redux doc).

```js
trait => trait.id === parseInt(action.payload.nativeEvent.path[1].id)
```

I read that `nativeEvent` was outdated so... that is that.

reducer:

```js
import {
    ADD_TRAIT,
    REMOVE_TRAIT,
    UPDATE_TRAIT
} from '../constants/actionTypes';

const initialState = [];

const traitsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_TRAIT:
            const newTrait= {};
            newTrait.trait = '';
            newTrait.id = state.length;
            for (let x =0; x<state.length; x++){
                if(state.find(node => node.id === x) === undefined){
                    newTrait.id = x;
                }
            }
            return[...state, newTrait];
        case UPDATE_TRAIT:
            const traitInState = state.find( 
                trait => trait.id === parseInt(action.payload.nativeEvent.path[1].id)
            );
            const traitIndex = state.indexOf(traitInState);
            const traitInStateObject = new Object;
            let keys;
            for(keys in traitInState){
                traitInStateObject[keys] = traitInState[keys];
            }
            traitInStateObject.trait = action.payload.target.value;
            return[
                ...state.map((item, index)=>
                    index === traitIndex 
                    ? traitInStateObject
                    : item
                )
            ];
        case REMOVE_TRAIT: 
            return state.filter((trait) => trait.id !== parseInt(action.payload.nativeEvent.path[1].id))
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default traitsReducer;
```

Trait.js has this element:

```
<div className='trait' id={id}>
  <textarea value={trait} cols='50' onChange={updateTrait}/>
  <button
    type='button'
    className='red delete deleteTrait'
    onClick={removeTrait}
  >
    x
  </button>
</div>
```

We got the `actionTypes.js` in constant folder and traitsActions.js in actions folder

traitsActions:

```js
import {
    ADD_TRAIT,
    UPDATE_TRAIT,
    REMOVE_TRAIT
} from '../constants/actionTypes';

export const updateTrait = trait => ({
    type: UPDATE_TRAIT,
    payload: trait
})

export const addTrait = trait =>({
    type:ADD_TRAIT,
    payload: trait
})

export const removeTrait = trait => ({
    type:REMOVE_TRAIT,
    payload: trait
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to use the native event to "look around" and gather the trait id and value I suggest just being more explicit with the action payloads that are dispatched. Don't use any event object but directly pass the trait `id` and current input value.

Example:

```js
export const updateTrait = (id, trait) => ({
  type: UPDATE_TRAIT,
  payload: { id, trait }
});

export const addTrait = () => ({
  type: ADD_TRAIT
});

export const removeTrait = (id) => ({
  type: REMOVE_TRAIT,
  payload: id
});
```

```js
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';

const initialState = [];

const traitsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TRAIT:
      return state.concat({
        trait: "",
        id: nanoid(),
      });

    case UPDATE_TRAIT:
      if (state.some((trait) => trait.id === action.payload.id)) {
        return state.map((trait) =>
          trait.id === action.payload.id
            ? { ...trait, trait: action.payload.trait }
            : trait
        );
      }
      return state;

    case REMOVE_TRAIT:
      return state.filter((trait) => trait.id !== action.payload);

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default traitsReducer;
```

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const traits = useSelector((state) => state.traits);

return (
  ...

  <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch(addTrait())}>
    Add Trait
  </button>

  {traits.map(({ id, trait }) => (
    <div className="trait" id={id} key={id}>
      <textarea
        value={trait}
        cols="50"
        onChange={(e) => dispatch(updateTrait(id, e.target.value))}
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        className="red delete deleteTrait"
        onClick={() => dispatch(removeTrait(id))}
      >
        x
      </button>
    </div>
  ))}

  ...
);
```

[image: Edit old-project-react-redux-nativeevent-path-undefined]

Note, you are using "legacy" Redux code patterns. It is *highly* recommended you update and use modern Redux using Redux-Toolkit. It cuts out much of the boilerplate code and you end up writing about 50% less code.

Example:

traitSlice.js - Replaces the action types, actions, reducer

```js
import { createSlice, nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = [];

const traitsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "traits",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addTrait: (state) => {
      state.push({
        trait: "",
        id: nanoid(),
      });
    },
    updateTrait: (state, action) => {
      const trait = state.find((trait) => trait.id === action.payload.id);

      if (trait) {
        trait.trait = action.payload.trait;
      }
    },
    removeTrait: (state, action) => {
      return state.filter((trait) => trait.id !== action.payload);
    }
  }
});

export const { addTrait, updateTrait, removeTrait } = traitsSlice.actions;

export default traitsSlice.reducer;
```

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { addTrait, removeTrait, updateTrait } from "./traitsSlice";

export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const traits = useSelector((state) => state.traits);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch(addTrait())}>
          Add Trait
        </button>
      </div>

      {traits.map(({ id, trait }) => (
        <div className="trait" id={id} key={id}>
          <textarea
            value={trait}
            cols="50"
            onChange={(e) =>
              dispatch(
                updateTrait({
                  id,
                  trait: e.target.value
                })
              )
            }
          />
          <button
            type="button"
            className="red delete deleteTrait"
            onClick={() => dispatch(removeTrait(id))}
          >
            x
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit old-project-react-redux-nativeevent-path-undefined (forked)]

Comment: Tanks for your answer ! You are right, I should look into Redux-toolkit.

Comment: It helped make me realize that it was better for me to learn the new way rather than trying to code along a tutorial made with legacy logic.
I did try to implement it but was soon stopped by my lack of knowledge.

Thanks a lot, I'm still at it and hope to reach my goal eventually.